# problems with NSMutabledata byteswithnocopy

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsmutabledata

I am trying to write a code to create NSMutableData from malloced buffer.I used freewhendone = YES
1) It gives an error in accessing the buffer after NSData is created.(in memset in below code)
2) The malloced buffer pointer and [data bytes] pointer are different.

Is there any explanation for these?

```
UWORD8 *rgb_buffer = malloc(u4_stride * u4_height * 3);

NSMutableData *rgbData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytesNoCopy:rgb_buffer

                                                     length:(u4_stride * u4_height * 3)

                                               freeWhenDone:YES];
memset(rgb_buffer, 0, (u4_stride * u4_height * 3));
```

Comment: You are likely running in ARC and aren't using the rgbData object after the memset; hence, it may be releasing the object early and thus freeing rgb_buffer.  See http://blog.bignerdranch.com/296-arc-gotcha-unexpectedly-short-lifetimes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Binary Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000717-149014)

> NSMutableData responds to dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:, but the bytes are copied
>   anyway and the buffer is freed immediately.

*It gives an error in accessing the buffer after NSData is created.(in memset in below code)*

buffer is freed immediately.

*The malloced buffer pointer and [data bytes] pointer are different.*

`NSMutableData` create copy of bytes.

Comment: `If you prefer that the bytes not be copied or freed when the object is released, you can use the dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: or initWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone: methods passing NO as the freeWhenDone: argument.`   
   This says that using this method bytes are not supposed to be copied. When I try this with freewhendone = NO  memset doesn't give segfault but the pointers are still different.

Comment: NSMutableData responds to these methods, too, but the bytes are copied anyway and the buffer is freed immediately.